# Hand built w3c Document Text node causes odd behavior

Tags: java, dom, document

The following code causes output that resembles the following:

```
<parent>
  <child/>  
  <secondChild/>  ...
```

I would anticipate it to look as follows:

```
<parent>  
parent text  
<child></child>  
<secondChild>second child text</secondChild>
```

The code in question is as follows:

```
Element parentNode= document.createElement("parent");
Text textNode = document.createTextNode("parent text");
Element childNode = document.createElement("child");
parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
childNode.appendChild(textNode);
childNode = document.createElement("secondChild");
textNode = document.createTextNode("second child text");
parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
childNode.appendChild(textNode);
```

My question is is there something I am missing by re-referencing the `textNode` that causes an issue when building a Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected for me. Maybe there's a problem with how you're printing it out? Try this:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class ThrowawayCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element parentNode = document.createElement("parent");
        document.appendChild(parentNode);
        Text textNode = document.createTextNode("parent text");
        Element childNode = document.createElement("child");
        parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
        childNode.appendChild(textNode);
        childNode = document.createElement("secondChild");
        textNode = document.createTextNode("second child text");
        parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
        childNode.appendChild(textNode);

        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, result);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><parent><child>parent text</child><secondChild>second child text</secondChild></parent>
```

**Edit:** If you really mean that you want the first text outside of the child instead of inside it, you need to change your code to:

```
Text textNode = document.createTextNode("parent text");
Element childNode = document.createElement("child");
parentNode.appendChild(textNode);
parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
```

but I assumed you had just mistyped the XML.

Comment: I do the following: `String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();`

Comment: @Woot: The result is the same either way.

Comment: I would agree, it should be the same.

Comment: @Woot: I also added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you cannot reuse any node. In a DOM, each node has a parent, and only one parent, once you attach a node (be it a text node or an element), that node is attached and should not be attached to any other parent node if not detached first.

DOM is rather ancient, and is not the easiest way to work with xml, not in java nor in any other platform (since it's a standard interface which is the same on almost all platforms).

Have you tried jdom or dom4j?

Comment: Is there any documentation that could validate your claims?

Comment: it implements node, so it has a getParentNode. In java documentation for this interface, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getParentNode() it's never stated that a node can have more than one parent, and there is no documented exception for text ndes, so you cannot add the same node to two different parents without expecting it to be removed from the previous parent.

Comment: However, documentation apart, does it work differently if you use two different text nodes instead of reusing one?